# Algebraic proof for sphere/circle overlap formula

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

Two spheres or circles denoted by center position vector and radius $ p_0, r_0$ and $p1, r_1$ will overlap if $$ |p_0-p_1| < r_0+r_1$$
I understand geometrically why it works, but how would one derive this formula using only algebra, using for example the equation of the sphere : $|c-x|^2=r^2$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that the two spheres have equations:
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
\big| x - p_0 \big| &= r_0 \\
\big| x - p_1 \big| &= r_1
\end{align}
\right.
$$

Then, the [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) yields
$$
\big| p_0 - p_1 \big| \le \big| x - p_0 \big| + \big| x - p_1 \big| = r_0 + r_1
$$
if and only if such a point $x$ exists on both spheres simultaneously.

Comment: I'm lost on how you got the $|p_0-p_1|$ bit using the triangle inequality. Also is it right that you are saying the inequality will only be true if such an $ x $ exists?